# Rich Internet Application Archetype or Web Application Archetype

Tags: model-view-controller, ria, knockout.js

Given the 2 Archetype name above ([and describe from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658104.aspx)) how do you <strike>call</strike> classify an MVC application using [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) to generate the UI?

Do you <strike>call</strike> classify it as a RIA or a WA?

Would you still use ASP.NET MVC with knockoutjs or would you use a different pattern for the server side layer?

Answer (score 3):

Call it what you want....

> ```
> "What's in a name? That which we call a rose
> By any other name would smell as sweet."
>                               William Shakespeare
> ```

[image: RIA Architecture]

[image: Web Application Architecture]

If you look at the application architecture diagrams, the RIA application uses a browser plugin (so Flash or Silverlight) to deliver a "rich" user interface where the Web Applciation does not.  So to answer your question according to the link you provided, an MVC application with a javascript library is a Web Application.

However, it is possible to create rich UI using javascript these days so the distinction is less clear.

Comment: I tried to add images but I'm not sure if they are blocked by my company firewall or if I've done it all wrong.